# Javascript memoization without closure scope

Tags: javascript, closures, memoization

In *Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja* the author's propose the below scheme for memoizing function results without a closure.  They do this by exploiting the fact that functions are objects and defining a property on the function that stores the results of past calls to the function.

```
function isPrime(value) {
    if (!isPrime.answers) isPrime.answers = {};
    if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
        return isPrime.answers[value];
    }
    var prime = value != 1
    for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if (value % i === 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
}
```

I have two questions

1. Their logic makes sense to me, but when I run the code all that happens is the answers property is created but nothing gets added to it - why?
2. The line `return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;` is funny to me, and repl.it warns when I use it. Is assigning and returning all in the same line frowned upon?

Comment: Try replacing isPrime with this

Comment: @ayushgp: Why? That would be wrong. What do you think `this` will refer to?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5u0ua5bp/ . `isPrime.answers` as an object with property 42.

Comment: I'm with @FelixKling, it worked for me locally. Potentially dumb question, did you *call* the function before checking for the value of answers?

Comment: @FelixKling I think it should refer to the function object. It doesn't, I checked. But then what does it refer to?

Comment: @ayushgp: it primarily depends on how the function is *called*, which is not shown here. But if it's called like `isPrime(n)`, then `this` will either refer to `window` (the global object) or `undefined` (if the code is in strict mode). In order for `this` to refer to the function itself, it would have to be explicitly set, e.g. via `isPrime.call(isPrime, n)`, which is rather uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Their logic makes sense to me, but when I run the code all that happens is the answers property is created but nothing gets added to it - why?

It seems to work just fine for me.

```
console.log(isPrime(42));
console.log(isPrime.answers)
```

shows that `answers` is a non-empty object:

[image]

```js
function isPrime(value) {
    if (!isPrime.answers) isPrime.answers = {};
    if (isPrime.answers[value] != null) {
        return isPrime.answers[value];
    }
    var prime = value != 1
    for (var i = 2; i < value; i++) {
        if (value % i === 0) {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
}

console.log(isPrime(42));
console.log(isPrime.answers)
```

> 2. [...] Is assigning and returning all in the same line frowned upon?

In this situation, the assignment is basically a [*side effect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), and side effects are frowned upon. That said, assignments being expressions and returning the assigned value is a feature of the language and as long as it's used responsibly, why not.

Answer (score 1):

> Their logic makes sense to me

It should not. The scheme still relies on closure, in particular over the `isPrime` variable in the scope that the function resides in. They could equally have used `var isPrimeAnswers = {};` instead of `isPrime.answers = {};` (both of which should be put outside of the function body).

> Is assigning and returning all in the same line frowned upon?

Depends on whom you ask, but it's not unanimously condemned as a bad practise. You say it's funny, others find it confusing, I personally think it's crystal clear. If you're not into code golf and want to be on the safe side, it's better to simply split it in two statements:

```
isPrime.answers[value] = prime;
return prime;
```

Comment: But `isPrime.answers` will persist across invocations, whereas `var` would not.

Comment: @torazaburo: A `var` outside of the function (i.e. the same scope as `isPrime` is in) would.